# NoClassDefFoundError - Apenas em execução via Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

Olá,

Tenho um projeto de automação com selenium + java + maven integrado no Jenkins. Hoje fiz um refactor nele movendo algumas classes para novos pacotes.

Na minha maquina não há problema algum de compilação e nem de execução, roda tudo normal. Porém no jenkins, que está em outra maquina, quando vou executar esse projeto (sempre chamando mvn clean install) ele está dando **NoClassDefFoundError** para uma das classes que mudei de pacote.

Como sou novo em java fui dar uma olhada para entender isso tudo, vi algumas pessoas dizendo para acrescentar a classe no classpath, vi as explicações sobre compilação e tempo de execução, etc. Eu não entendo o porque de, na minha máquina não ter dado erro em tempo de execução também.

Gostaria de saber como corrigir isso. Quando eu edito o classpath não aponto o caminho da classe na minha máquina? Sendo que o jenkins baixa o projeto do git e executa em outra máquina, como isso funcionaria?

Se alguém puder me explicar a melhor solução para corrigir esse erro, pois não sei mexer no classpath. Como isso aconteceu quando fiz um refactor de packages não há como zerar essas referências inválidas?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Respondendo minha própria pergunta...

Depois de muito procurar na internet, no código, e tudo mais, eu vi que um comentário em uma comunidade onde um usuário dizia que essa exceção as vezes não é jogada só quando a classe não é encontrada em tempo de execução, ele dizia que as vezes isso acontece por causa de outro erro no código, que não tem nada a ver com alterar classpath e afins.

No final das contas eu fiz um try catch em uma parte do código que eu desconfiava que podia estar causando algum erro, e de fato erra isso, o catch pegou uma exceção do selenium totalmente diferente da **NoClassDefFoundError**, pegou a exceção **org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException**, arrumei então um problema que encontrei nas capabilities do chrome driver e tudo está ok agora.